# Sveltekit undefined error when deleting a store with bind:this bindings

Tags: binding, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I have a store called **$columns** that can bind sections of html to a property

```
{#each $columns[key].sections as section, i (section.id)}
    {#if $columns[key].sections[i].chapter}
        <div bind:this={$columns[key].sections[i].dom}>
                {@html section.chapter}
        </div>
    {/if} 
{/each}
```

but when I delete a column

pre-troubleshooting way:
`$columns = $columns.filter((el, index) => index !== key)`

**EDIT Troubleshooting delete Function**:

```
async function removeColumn() {
        if ($columns[key] && $columns[key].sections) {
            $columns[key].sections.forEach(section => {
                if (section.dom) {
                    section.dom = null;
                }
                delete section.dom
            });
        }
        // Just going crazy here:
        if ($columns[key] && $columns[key].sections) {
            $columns[key].sections.forEach(section => {
            if (section.dom && section.dom.parentNode) {
                section.dom.parentNode.removeChild(section.dom);
            }
        });
        }
        console.log($columns[key].sections)
        await tick();
        
        // a deep copy inside the timeout
        setTimeout(() => {
            $columns = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($columns)).filter((el, index) => index !== key);
        }, 100);
}
```

sveltekit still throws a undefined error

> Column.svelte:47 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1142') at Column.svelte:47:42
> at flush (index.mjs:1320:35)

Removing the binding completely fixes the error on removal, but the binding is working well in all other respects and behaving as expected. The error only occurs when the parent `$column[key]` is removed.

It seems like component.$destroy(); is for whole components rather than bindings and I've attempted to use `await tick();` to allow for the `binding_callbacks.pop()` to finish but no luck yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `#each` is lacking [a key](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each).

Comment: I added {#each $columns[key].sections as section, i (section.id)} as there is an id in the section object but it's still throwing an error. I've also tried deleting the bindings before removing the object containing them.

Comment: Every instance of `$columns[key].sections[i]` can be replaced by just `section`, there should not be any need to declare `i` in the first place here. Also, using `bind:this` in an `#each` is just a recipe for disaster, I would never do that. Why do you need the node in your list?

Comment: binding it to a variable seemed the preferred way to go to preform operations on each section.chapter. Things like highlights, text replacement, ect from other components that have access to the store.

Comment: Well, you will have to be careful with that. If you mess with the DOM, subsequent changes to `chapter` or an invalidation of the section as a whole will re-create the HTML, thus overwriting any manual modifications. The preferred way of things is to use direct markup, `bind:this` and `@html` should be used rarely if ever; quite often `bind:this` can be replaced with [actions](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#use-action).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by changing the foreach to this by adding a fallback empty array for the sections loop and combining it with the good advice from HB

````
{#each $columns[key]?.sections || [] as section, i (section.id)}
        {#if section.chapter}
            <div bind:this={section.dom}>
                {@html section.chapter}
            </div>
        {/if} 
{/each}```
````